# Как сделать пененос на новую строку перед заданными словами?

Tags: python, строки, парсер

Сделал я парсер для сайта. Оттуда он вытаскивает название игр и их ссылки. После того как пользователь выбирает номер игры, я парсю информацию о ней - Дата выхода, системные требования и прочее. Проблема в том, что вся эта информация находиться в одном **div** и разделена **br**. То есть при выходе у меня выходит все одной сплошной строкой.
Вот как это смотрится на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как дела обстоят на самом сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать перенос на новую строку перед определенным словом?
Допустим

```
"Дата выхода: 5 мар. 2015(новая строка как только перед "Жанр")Жанр: Экшены, Приключенческие, Ролевые, Симуляторы(новая строка как только перед "Разработчик")Разработчик: Last Bastion 
 Studios LLC
```

И тому подобное для всех строк.
Я знаю, что это можно как сделать с помощью модуля Re, вопрос только как?
Буду рад и другим способам.

Мой код парсера - https://github.com/FreedomEssence/Torrent-Ighruha_Parser/blob/master/__init__.py

Сайт который парсю - https://torrent-igruha.org/

Comment: попробуйте `.get_text('\n')`

Comment: Всю информацию для ответа в сам вопрос, а не по ссылкам

Comment: @5corp В принципе работает, но переносит увы все. Нашел решение, правда нормальные программисты мне бы за него руки отрвали...
Вообщем вот: # t = text.replace('Жанр:', '\nЖанр:').replace('Разработчик:','\nРазработчик:').replace('Издатель:','\nИздатель:').replace('Язык интерфейса:','\nЯзык интерфейса:').replace('Язык озвучки:','\nЯзык озвучки:').replace('Таблетка:','\nТаблетка:').replace('Системные требования:','\nСистемные требования:').replace('ОС','\nОС')

Comment: Свой код добавьте в вопрос. Свой вопрос вы можете редактировать.